What's this big buried block outside a Bowing foundation wall

So my basement wall is bowing so I’m have a company come out and put beams up and push the wall back to being straight. While digging the outside I found this on the outside wall right where the wall is cracking a bunch. Just wondering if anyone knows what it could be. It’s cemented into the wall.
Just bought the house a year ago so I have no idea what was done before to the house.

underpinning perhaps

No chance it was a previous attempt to arrest the bowing?
